# HTML/JQuery: Textarea enlargement; Need to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When user enter text in textarea; it enlarge automatically.

Now User enter lengthy text, till area enlarge to bottom.

When user reach on bottom of page (which is another static footer div) then in enlarging textarea; text stop getting displayed and goes to back of footer and user need to scroll.

I could not paste whole code. Following are snippet for reference:

```
<div class="ionTabs" style="width: 100%; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" >

<! -- There is huge piece of code here using IONTABS... In one of Tab we have following textarea  -->

 <textarea id="financeComments" style="overflow: hidden; width: 90%; resize: none; height: 20px; "></textarea>

</div>
<!-- The textarea in above div get expand and enters into following footer after which we are unable to view text and need to scroll down   -->

<div class="footer economySubmit">
  Footer Data
</div>
```

Following is screenshot of issue in which 15 is getting hidden and scroll gets appeared:

[image]

**Update**:
Required CSS for reference.

```
.footer {
 background: #f1f1f1 none repeat scroll 0 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 43px;
 left: 0;
 padding: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Likely a css issue. Without code we will never know. Create a snippet

Comment: There is inline css on this tags which are there in snippet above.

Comment: In my opinion `textarea` is actually getting extended but its **`hidden`** behind `footer`. So in these type of situations set a `max-height` to `textarea` and keep `overflow:scroll`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao 
You understood it right. Lemme try that.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao : No if i change to scroll then scroll comes around textarea.

Comment: The position fixed of the footer seems to be the reason

Comment: @mplungjan
But i am not suppose to change that. It should be fix at bottom.

Comment: I think need to scroll more

Comment: Then add `overflow:scroll` to `.ionTabs`

Comment: What is your question? It's very unclear what you are asking here.

Comment: @Amasa
I want to keep Textarea in front of user eye; when user is entering text. But when user enter long text as shown in screenshot above. The textarea/text goes back to footer div.

Comment: It's logical!!! Are you thinking of putting a max-height to the textarea? Can you sacrifice user experience instead of a simply scroll when the textarea is too large?

Comment: @Marcos Perez Gude 
NO I could not sacrifice that :(

Comment: so put `textarea { max-height: 400px; overflow-y: auto; }` where you change 400 pixels by the max height you need to add.

Comment: @MArcos Perez Gude
But that will display Scroll Bar inside textarea which user do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to evaluate the div > textarea content & event. I have written a demo code for textarea, in which if user click "enter", then textarea height will be increased by 5px;

```
<script>
    $('textarea').keyup(
    function(event){
        var t = $(this).val();
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            $(this).height($(this).height()+5);
        }       
    });
</script>
```

This function could be further enhanced for total characters in textarea & enter key read. Let's try this approach to avoid scroll in textarea.

You could eliminate scroll by adding attribute property as `"scroll:none;"` too, but this will reduce the Usability.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually in this scenario; the text goes up and hide above textarea and recent text which is put is getting displayed only. 

And the issue which i am facing is still not getting resolved with this